# How to access the BRANCH_NAME variable within a Jenkins pipeline running on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote a Jenkins pipeline which git clones a repository, builds feature branches code and if everything is finished successfully it should merge the branch to master.

here's the relevant code:

```
stage ('Merge to master') {
    if(currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS') {
        bat """
            cd %workspace%
            echo "BRANCH_NAME: %BRANCH_NAME%"
            echo "Env.BRANCH_NAME: %env.BRANCH_NAME%
            git checkout master
            REM git merge %GIT_BRANCH%
        """
    }
}
```

The code which is responsible for the cloning:

```
stage ('Checkout SCM') { // This stage is responsible to clone the repository into Jenkins's workspace
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/feature/*']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '99f978af-XXXX-XXXX-8147-2cf8f69ef864', url: 'http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/repo-name']]])
}
```

My problem is that it seems like the BRANCH_NAME variable is not set, I've tried accessing it by `%BRANCH_NAME%` , `%env.BRANCH_NAME%`, `%GIT_BRANCH%` and `%env.GIT_BRANCH%` but to no avail.

In Jenkins build log, it looks like that:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure>echo "BRANCH_NAME: " 
"BRANCH_NAME: "

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure>echo "Env.BRANCH_NAME:  
"Env.BRANCH_NAME: 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure>echo "GIT_BRANCH: " 
"GIT_BRANCH: "

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure>echo "Env.GIT_BRANCH: env.GIT_BRANCH" 
"Env.GIT_BRANCH: env.GIT_BRANCH"
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: Check my answer on this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006070/jenkins-gitscm-finishes-the-clone-in-a-detached-head-state-how-can-i-make-sure/44023516#44023516

Answer (score 0):

You need to interpolate the string value using the Groovy placeholders ${}, i.e. ${env.BRANCH_NAME}

This will replace the variable with the string literal before the batch script is executed.  The %% notation is for interpolating windows environment variables, but env.BRANCH_NAME is Jenkins environment variable not a windows environment variable.

Comment: Just to add... the Jenkins variable env.BRANCH_NAME only seems to work for me as part of a Jenkinsfile.  When running as a freestyle job I had to get the branch by running a Git shell command within a script step: `branch = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()`

Comment: It's a windows Jenkins so no "sh", also it doesn't work as you said... I need it to work in pipeline, any idea how?

Comment: for windows use `bat`.

Like this: `branch = bat (script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD', returnStdout: true).trim()`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. "manage jenkins" -> "Configure System" ... scroll down to "Global Properties" and check the checkbox for "Environmental Variables".
2. Add your variable (i.e. Name: MY_BRANCH, value: "*/master")
3. Restart Jenkins
4. Go to your build then you can use the variable in your build configs as ${MY_BRANCH}