# Jenkins: GitSCM finishes the clone in a detached head state, how can I make sure that the correct branch name is checked out?

Tags: git, jenkins

I wrote a Jenkins pipeline which clones a git repository and runs a MSBUILD build.

I use GitSCM to clone the repository into the workspace like so:

```
stage ('Checkout SCM & Merge master to feature branch') {
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/feature/*']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '99f978af-XXXX-XXXX-8147-2cf8f69ef864', url: 'http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/REPO_NAME']]])
}
```

After the step of cloning the repo takes place, HEAD is pointing to a detached head and I don't understand why.

```
Started by user itai ganot
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bbb
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Setup)
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout SCM & Merge master to feature branch)
[Pipeline] checkout
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository http://pctfs1:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/Ensure-pcs-intl
 > git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bbb # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/Ensure-pcs-intl
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials javab SSH file
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/REPO_NAME +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/REPO_NAME # timeout=10
 > git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/REPO_NAME # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/REPO_NAME
using GIT_SSH to set credentials javab SSH file
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/REPO_NAME +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/merge_tfs
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen branch in repository origin/origin
Seen 3 remote branches
 > git.exe tag -l # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 97b3493db4f726e11e334e5ba34fa808b63edec5 (origin/feature/merge_tfs)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 97b3493db4f726e11e334e5ba34fa808b63edec5
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] bat
[bbb] Running batch script

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bbb>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bbb 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\bbb>git branch 
* (HEAD detached at 97b3493)
```

More than that, it is known that when running a Jenkins pipeline, git parameters are not evaluated correctly and because of that I can't fix it by simply running:

```
git checkout ${BRANCH_NAME}
```

So how can I make sure before starting the MSBUILD step that HEAD is pointing to the branch name?

I'm sure someone has already bumped into this situation and has a solution.

Comment: BRANCH_NAME is the one scm-related environment variable that *is* set for in my pipelines. so i do `sh 'git checkout ' + env.BRANCH_NAME`, but i think your version should do the same thing (if it were set). :|

Comment: BRANCH_NAME variable is not evaluated properly and when I print it I get 'null' as the value.

Comment: BRANCH_NAME or env.BRANCH_NAME only shows up in some environments. My suspicion is it's related to the version of Git, plugins on the Jenkins box and/or their interaction. (Remember, some diehards won't update Git past the originally installed version, which is something like 1.8.3 on the instance I use now. ... I'm guessing about 8 years old.)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After lots of researching and even contacting Jenkins professionals and many tries from my side, I found how to solve this issue.

The following code fixes the issue:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/feature/*']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "**"]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '99f978af-XXXX-XXXX-8147-2cf8f69ef864', url: 'http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Product/_git/Project']]])
```

Notice the `"**"` in the `localBranch` extension.

Jenkins log:

```
Checking out Revision 97b3493db4f726e11e33XXXba34fa808b63edec5 (origin/feature/merge_tfs)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f 97b3493db4f726e11e33XXXba34fa808b63edec5
 > git.exe branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -b feature/merge_tfs 97b3493db4f726e11e33XXXba34fa808b63edec5
 > git.exe rev-list 97b3493db4f726e11e334e5ba34fa808b63edec5 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] bat
[Ensure] Running batch script

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Ensure>git branch 
* feature/merge_tfs
```

Comment: My head is a bit sore from banging it on the wall. Thank you so MUCH!

Comment: This is crazy! I tried for hours to get rid of a detached HEAD state after Jenkins' initial clone and the `**` in the `localBranch` are really doing the trick! Do you have any explanation to why they help??

Comment: Hi, found your post five years later while facing the same issue with a multibranch pipeline. I'm not using the checkout step in code, it's configured in Jenkins in "Branch Sources". Is there a way to make it work for that too? thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Adding `[[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "**"]]` fixed my issue.

After a successful checkout of master branch using `GitSCM` plugin, `.git/refs/heads/master` was still missing making some operations to always fail (e.g. `git log --decorate ...` to create changelog).

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: You're right but I'm new in stackoverflow so I got a "You must have a 50 reputation to comment" popup when I clicked on "add a comment"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the same behavior using Pipeline configurations, use Pipeline->Additional Behaviours -> Checkout to specific local branch -> insert branch name (or '**') in the input field.

[My pipeline snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMsLb.png)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61063557/6776354, updating `checkout scm`
to

```
                def scmVars = checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: scm.branches,
                    extensions: scm.extensions, 
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                        credentialsId: scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].credentialsId,
                        name: 'origin', 
                        refspec: '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*', 
                        url: scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].url
                    ]],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false
                ])
```

worked for me. This made sure all branches are available.

Comment: I'm sure it does work better now, 6 years after asking this question :)