# Force jenkins to fetch all branches at any build

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm using a jenkins multibranch pipeline job to perform various checks and merges between branches and tags on one repository.
The SCM fetch is done using these scm extensions to make sure that all branches and tags are fetched in the workspace (param "Honor refspec on initial clone" unchecked especially):

```
[[$class: 'PruneStaleBranch'], [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false]]
```

It works fine for the first build when the workspace is empty:

```
git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://scmServer/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

But not on subsequent builds where jenkins only fetches the branch that is associated with the job:

```
git fetch --tags --force --progress --prune -- https://scmServer/repo.git +refs/heads/release/10.0.0:refs/remotes/origin/release/10.0.0
```

In this case, other branches such as master are not fetched and get out of date in the workspace compared to what's on the origin.

One ugly solution would be to wipe the workspace at every build but i would prefer to avoid that. How can i force Jenkins fetch all branches for all builds?
One explanation of this behavior may lie in the name of the option "Honor refspec on initial clone". As i'm not in the initial clone, this option may not apply and the default behavior on non initial builds looks to be to honor refspec.

Comment: i think the issue lies in the refspec provided by default in the scm object in multibranch pipeline:

`scm.userRemoteConfigs: [+refs/heads/release/1.0.0:refs/remotes/origin/release/1.0.0 => https://scmServer/repo.git (origin)]`

I'll try to figure out how we can edit this to fetch refs/heads/*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was indeed related to the refspec that comes by default in the scm object of a multibranch pipeline. The refspec in such context is specific to the branch being built. It's just ignored during the first build and only the first build if the param 'honor refspec on initial clone' is set to false.

I tried to edit or update the refspec of the scm map but it did not work, so i just created a new one and copy the attributes i needed + a custom refspec to fetch all branches

```
    def scmVars = checkout([
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: scm.branches,
        extensions: scm.extensions, 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[
            credentialsId: scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].credentialsId,
            name: 'origin', 
            refspec: '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*', 
            url: scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].url
        ]],
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false
    ])
```